# How to include a partial into another partial's block?

Tags: node.js, template-engine, swig-template

I use [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) as a template engine.

I need to include a partial but only into another partial's block. But Swig includes it just below, ignoring a block tag. Here is how it looks:

**1.**

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}
        {% block headtag %}
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/css/global.css' />
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' />
            <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container cmt">

            {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2.**

This is a page view that is rendered after request.

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'layouts/layout.html' %}


{% block title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block headtag %}
    {% parent %}
    <link href="/assets/css/index/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}



{% block content %}

    {% include 'index_content.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

**3.**

Here I include a header partial (`partials/header.html`). And this header partial has an empty block tag (`header_nav`) in which I want to include another partial (`header_nav.html`). But only into the block. See the **header.html** lower.

**index_content.html**

```
{% include 'partials/header.html' %}

{% block header_nav %}
    {% include 'header_nav.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**4.**

Here is an html-code of the `partials/header.html`. See the block tag `header_nav`. In that block I want to place **header_nav.html**. But it doesn't work. It places **header_nav.html** just bellow **partials/header.html**:

```
<div class="clearfix mb30">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="logo_div" class="">
                <div class="logo_div">
                    <a href="/" title="">
                        <span class="logo_span"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9 hctrlbar">

            {% block header_nav %}
                ... I want to include a partial here only ...
            {% endblock %}

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

... But Swig ignores header_nav block and places here for some reason ...
```

How to acheave it? As I understand for now this is a real drawback of Swig. Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, this cannot be done.

Take a look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779284/how-an-included-partial-insert-code-into-parents-block?rq=1).
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780514/3220829) comment there's a link to a related issue on [github](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/147).

[paularmstrong](https://github.com/paularmstrong) wrote:

> Blocks are not supported in included templates. You should (be able to) structure your extends/inheritance to accomplish the same thing...
>
> ...You should use multiple extends...
> Blocks in includes will never be supported.

There's also an example similar to yours that you might want to check out.